# What does "error: ld returned 1 exit status" mean?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm programming in C with Code::Blocks 16.01 and often I can't compile my programs. My compiler (GNU GCC) returns the following error: "error: ld returned 1 exit status". My program is very simple and I have reasons to believe that it is correct.

Does anyone knows what that error means?

Comment: please add some more information about your project. Include any additional error messages the linker is outputting, otherwise you cannot debug this issue.

Comment: You can download a free version of Visual Studio called Visual Studio Community edition if you fall under certain guidelines, such as being a programmer without a team. The reason I'm saying this is that I think Code::Blocks has been discontinued for a long time.

Comment: -------------- Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe   -c "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\New folder\lab5\main.c" -o "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\New folder\lab5\main.o"
mingw32-g++.exe  -o "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\New folder\lab5\main.exe" "C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\New folder\lab5\main.o"   
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: impossibile aprire il file di output C:\Users\Davide\Desktop\New folder\lab5\main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status